# Limit memory on Heroku Scheduler

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a few scheduled tasks on **Heroku Scheduler** addon and I'm hitting the memory limit on a few of them. According to [Heroku docs](https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#7-avoid-garbage), this is because NodeJs lazy behaviour. I need to explicitly define the memory allocated for the process (512Mb) but not sure how to do it from the Scheduler interface.

This is how it looks when I run it locally:

```
node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=512 myTask.js
```

Any idea about passing these values to the Scheduler or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you can pass the extra args to Heroku Scheduler task.

> The scheduler uses the same one-off dynos that heroku run uses to
>   execute your jobs, so you can be assured that if it works with heroku
>   run, it will work from the scheduler. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#testing-tasks

So basically you should be able to test out the command before with `heroku run node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=512 myTask.js`. The 512MB limit isn't hard limit, so it's not a problem if it shortly reaces the ~530MB limit.